# Common code for several activities in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have more than 3 activities which require bluetooth connectivity. All activities connect to a bluetooth before continuing process. If no bluetooth connection, it'll load another activity `DevicesListActivity`, which basically lists all the nearby devices and user can select one of them. On clicking a device, it returns with the selected device back to one of the 3 activity. Now in `onActivityResult`, i make the connection and continue processing. So i'm having same code in `onActivityResult` for all the 3 activities.

Kindly suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Define a common parent-Activity and have each Activity extend it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a different class named `BluetoothConnection` with methods you need to do that. Then just create in every class the object and there you have your global class.

It's something like this:

```
BluetoothConnection a = new BluetoothConnection();
a.startConnection();//Or the methods u have to create connections
```

Since you have your external Class you can create an object of this Class and work with it. I hope it helps you.

Comment: this is exactly wat i do. I do the same code in all 3 activities. I am looking for some other alternative. This creates duplicate code.

Comment: Well, that's just 3 code lines so its not much "duplicated" code. On the other hand, it's dangerous to create global variable because if you create it on an activity and you change activity it might not exist when you want access to it. Android might close non-used activities to optimize RAM use so in my opinion its the best and most secure way to do it